# jquery switch divs with button click not work

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle

I want two divs to be switched (one shows instead in place of other one) when the button is clicked, but when I click on the button, the button disappears and div is not switched.

```
<button id="change" class="btn">Change</button>
<div id="FTE" style="border:2px solid #09F">
    Contents 1
</div>

<div id="ETF" style="border:2px solid #09F">
    Contents 2
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ETF").show();
    $("#FTE").hide();
    $("#change").click(function () {
        $("#change").toggle(function (){
            $("#change").text("First");
            $("#FTE").hide(1000);
        }, function() {
            $("#change").text("Second");
            $("#ETF").show(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "switching the divs"?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vVNmM/?

Comment: all youre ever doing here is applying show to an already shown element and hide to an already hidden element, over and over

Comment: @j08691 yes thanks you that is what I want but I also want to change the button text. Your example is not changing the text of the button.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsbin.com/alomew/4/edit

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand

    $("#ETF").show();
    $("#FTE").hide();

    var changeTxt = ["Second","First"];

    $("#change").click(function () {       
        $(this).text( changeTxt.reverse()[0] );
        $("#FTE, #ETF").toggle( 1000 );      
    });

});
```

I was tired of using the [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to toggle two values,
`$(this).text( $(this).text() == "foo" ? "bar" : "foo" );`

 so recently I figured a nice little trick:

`changeTxt.reverse()[0]` (like the name already suggests) will reverse on every click our `changeTxt` Array and take the *first* (0 indexed) Array Key value.

<sub>Additional docs:</sub>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 2):

.toggle() changes the visibility of the matched element (the button). And then you try to hide the already hidden FTE-element and show the already showing ETF-element.